# Vuex-OIDC - Required oidc setting authority missing for creating UserManager

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex, openid-connect

Hei guys, hope there is someone that can help me!

I am trying to use OIDC in my app, but I am getting the error in the title:
"Uncaught Error: Required oidc setting authority missing for creating UserManager"
I am using vuex-oidc in a Nuxt application.

This is my .env:

```
BASE_URL = http://localhost:3000/
AUTHORITY = https://***/***/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1A_SEAMLESSMIGRATION_SIGNUPORSIGNIN
CLIENT_ID = *****
TOKEN_ENDPOINT = https://***/***/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=B2C_1A_SEAMLESSMIGRATION_SIGNUPORSIGNIN
RESPONSE_TYPE = id_token
SCOPE = https://***/***/Read openid
```

and here is my oidc.js file (in the store) which contains the oidc-settings:

```
import { vuexOidcCreateStoreModule } from 'vuex-oidc'

const oidcSettings = {
  authority: process.env.AUTHORITY,
  clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  token_endpoint: process.env.TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
  redirectUri: process.env.BASE_URL + '/callback',
  responseType: process.env.RESPONSE_TYPE,
  scope: process.env.SCOPE
}

const storeModule = vuexOidcCreateStoreModule(
  oidcSettings,
  {
    namespaced: true,
    dispatchEventsOnWindow: true,
    publicRoutePaths: ['/', 'oidc-callback-error']
  },
  {
    userLoaded: user => console.log('OIDC user is loaded:', user),
    userUnloaded: () => console.log('OIDC user is unloaded'),
    accessTokenExpiring: () => console.log('Access token will expire'),
    accessTokenExpired: () => console.log('Access token did expire'),
    silentRenewError: () => console.log('OIDC user is unloaded'),
    userSignedOut: () => console.log('OIDC user is signed out')
  }
)

export const state = () => (storeModule.state)

export const getters = storeModule.getters

export const actions = storeModule.actions

export const mutations = storeModule.mutations
```

Am I missing something? Is someone that knows why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked our OIDC config. Shouldn't the `authority` be an OIDC URL ending with `/authorize` ?

Comment: Is this a rhetorical answer and supposed to answer the question, or a question you have about your own code/situation? In case of the former: please [edit] the question to explain why this answers the question, see [answer]. In case of the latter: delete this and instead [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).